# Deploy multiple services in docker-compose.yml using hub, on own server (django)

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, deployment, dockerhub

I've a Django project, and i'm using docker with a docker-compose file + DockerFile and .env folder with user/pass for access. Locally, it's working fine.

I wonder if I can push all the services (web, postgres and pgadmin) in the same times. After, on my own server, I would pull them all.

For now, I push 2 services (web + postgres) on the docker's hub, and pull them. But when I run the postgres/postgis image with "-e" parameter. But I don't like this solution because the docker-compose file don't "help me" to deploy.
And, how can I use the ".env/" folder (see docker-compose.yml) instead of using "-e" parameter ?

```
#./dj/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - ./env/django.env
    build:
         context: ./my_project
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    container_name: web_container_my_project
    image: my_company/my_project_web_api_my_project
    volumes:
      - ./my_project:/opt/my_project
    ports:
      # HOST:CONTAINER
      - "8050:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

  db:
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Paris
    env_file:
      - ./env/postgresql.env
    image: postgis/postgis
    container_name: postgres_container_my_project
    hostname: db
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data-my_project:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      # HOST:CONTAINER
      - "5433:5432"
    restart: always

  pgadmin:
    env_file:
      - ./env/pgadmin.env
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin_container_my_project
    ports:
      # HOST:CONTAINER
      - "8059:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/pgadmin/data:/var/lib/pgadmin/data
    links:
      - "db:pgsql-server"
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: none

volumes:
  pgadmin_data:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

Thanks a lot
F.